# Simple signatures style

Tags: formatting

I would like to make signatures on my document like this. I'm using `\documentclass{article}`

[image]

Comment: This is text (centered) and rules (`\rule{extwidth}{.4pt}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using an outstretched `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764
  \begin{tabular}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.5\linewidth}}
    \hline
    Prof.~Dr.~Beltrano Garcia -- Orientador \\
    \textit{Universidade Federal do Tocantins} \\[3\bigskipamount]
    \hline
    Profa.~Ma.~Fulana de Tal \\
    \textit{Centro Universit\'ario do Tocantins} \\[3\bigskipamount]
    \hline
    Prof.~Ms.~Ciclano de Tal \\
    \textit{Universidade Federal do Tocantins}
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Adjust the width `.5\linewidth` to suit your needs.